# undefined method `async=' for ActionMailer::Base:Class in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I am trying to use the new rails 4 asynchronous mailer based on the rails guide [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/6a8591525717821594e4ba7f0199b9a402b063db)

in my config/application.rb I added

```
config.action_mailer.async = true
```

and in my actionMailer I added

```
class welcomeMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    #self.async = true
end
```

these results in `undefined method async= for ActionMailer::Base:Class` when I try to run my `rails server`. I tried to rake my workers but rake will also fail due to this addition.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently they moved from asynchronous to synchronous with an external queue, and this behavior is used by default:

> Action Mailer async flag is true by default using a Synchronous impl

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/34b23e7110a3a13cf157608cefc9b5701017bf39

**Further update:**

Apparently they pulled the queuing functionality as well:

> Move background jobs to the 'jobs' branch until fully baked. Not shipping with Rails 4.0.

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/f9da785d0b1b22317cfca25c15fb555e9016accb

Comment: that is odd, because when I am sending out emails I can see my page loading and waiting for the emails to be sent

Comment: I posted an update to my update. Apparently there is no native out-of-band ActionMailer functionality. You'll probably have to go with a worker queuing system to get that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it ever made it!

```
farleyknight@farleyknight-desktop:~/tmp$ git clone git@github.com:rails/rails.git
Cloning into 'rails'...
remote: Finding bitmap roots...
remote: Counting objects: 394168, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (110181/110181), done.
remote: Total 394168 (delta 286616), reused 387911 (delta 280577)
Receiving objects: 100% (394168/394168), 93.88 MiB | 1.61 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (286616/286616), done.
farleyknight@farleyknight-desktop:~/tmp$ cd rails/
```

The only mentions of 'async' are under active_record, action_view/actionpack or the guides.

```
farleyknight@farleyknight-desktop:~/tmp/rails$ grep async . -r --exclude=*.js
Binary file ./.git/objects/pack/pack-2684dbd9d8af432c397e766784fb5ca058fec4c4.pack matches
./.git/packed-refs:61e31f2c8744eccd07c23d3fad2db9ea8504909b refs/remotes/origin/async
Binary file ./.git/index matches
./activerecord/test/cases/locking_test.rb:# (See exec vs. async_exec in the PostgreSQL adapter.)
./activerecord/lib/active_record/explain.rb:    # asynchronously by the subscriber and returned.
./activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:            result_as_array @connection.async_exec(sql)
./activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:            @connection.async_exec(sql)
./activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:          log(sql, name, binds) { @connection.async_exec(sql) }
./actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb:                           autoplay controls loop selected hidden scoped async
./guides/source/security.md:NOTE: _Make sure file uploads don't overwrite important files, and process media files asynchronously._
./guides/source/security.md:The solution to this is best to _process media files asynchronously_: Save the media file and schedule a processing request in the database. A second process will handle the processing of the file in the background.
./guides/source/form_helpers.md:Unlike other forms making an asynchronous file upload form is not as simple as providing `form_for` with `remote: true`. With an Ajax form the serialization is done by JavaScript running inside the browser and since JavaScript cannot read files from your hard drive the file cannot be uploaded. The most common workaround is to use an invisible iframe that serves as the target for the form submission.
./actionpack/test/controller/live_stream_test.rb:    def test_async_stream
```

Comment: so no built in async mailer :( sigh , guess I will have to find another way to deal with this

Comment: See my new answer. Apparently it's synchronous with a queue, which is almost as good I suppose. You certainly don't want to overload your CPU with 1000's of emails being sent at the same time.

Comment: I replied to the other answer as well :)